# PRE tag in bootstrap not displaying all code

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I trying to print all included code in the pre tag of bootstrap. But browser is displaying by hiding some code and below all tag.

**My pre tag code is as shown below**

```
<pre>
public class NumberPalindromeEx 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int numbers[]={12321,543,56765,4324},temp=0,reversenum=0;
        int rem=0;

        for(int i=0;i<numbers.length;i++)
        {
            temp = numbers[i];

            while(numbers[i]>0)
            {
                rem = numbers[i] % 10;
                reversenum = (reversenum * 10) + rem;
                numbers[i] = numbers[i] / 10;
            }

            if(temp == reversenum)
                System.out.println(temp+" is palindrome number\n");
            else
                System.out.println(temp+" is NOT palindrome number\n");

            reversenum = 0; // to clear previous value
        }   
    }
}
</pre> // this tag is showing red line in brackets.
```

**I'm getting output in browser as**

```
public class NumberPalindromeEx 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int numbers[]={12321,543,56765,4324},temp=0,reversenum=0;
        int rem=0;

        for(int i=0;i0)
            {
                rem = numbers[i] % 10;
                reversenum = (reversenum * 10) + rem;
                numbers[i] = numbers[i] / 10;
            }

            if(temp == reversenum)
                System.out.println(temp+" is palindrome number\n");
            else
                System.out.println(temp+" is NOT palindrome number\n");

            reversenum = 0; // to clear previous value
        }   
    }
}
```

Why does my while loop is missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `<` or `>` symbols, your browser may confuse it to HTML tags.
You should use `&lt;` and/or `&gt;` wherever you have these symbols like this.

```
for(int i=0; i &lt; numbers.length; i++) //use "&lt;"
```

and

```
 while(numbers[i] &gt; 0) //use "&gt;"
```

[More info here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Use `<xmp></xmp>` tag instead of `<pre></pre>`.

Comment: No i have recommonded <pre> tag only

Comment: Change < to &lt; in for, and > to &gt; in while relation.